# Can't call method "filename" without a package or object reference

Tags: perl, ftp, net-ftp

I want to download from a ftp server (host1) a bunch of directories with content. To do that I use library [Net::FTP::Recursive](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP::Recursive). When I run the code the folders and files were downloaded. Nevertheless, I got this message:

```
>Can't call method "filename" without a package or object reference 
 at C:\10_LIB~1\PerlLib\lib\perl5/Net/FTP/Recursive.pm line 86.
```

I wonder why this happens, what impact it has and how I can avoid this.

Here is the code to download:

```
# -- Libraries

# coding and diagnostic
use strict;
use warnings;

# FTP connection
use Net::FTP;
use Net::FTP::Recursive;

# -- Settings

my $host1      = "ftp.host1.com";
my $user1      = "myname\@myweb.com";
my $password1  = "password";

# -- Connection to ftp server

my $f1 = Net::FTP::Recursive->new($host1) or die "Can't open \$f1 $host1\n";
$f1->login($user1, $password1) or die "Can't log \$f1 $user1 in\n";
$f1->cwd() or die "Can't cwd to host folder\n";

# $f1->ascii();
$f1->binary;

# -- Directory to download the contents

my $download = "C:/mydirectory/download";
chdir($download);

# -- Host1

$f1->cwd();
$f1->rget( ParseSub => \&yoursub1 );
$f1->quit;    

sub yoursub1 {
$f1->rget;
}
```

I used perl on Windows 7 with version:

```
perl -v
This is perl 5, version 28, subversion 0 (v5.28.0) built for MSWin32-x64-multi-thread
```

And here is the code from /Net/FTP/Recursive.pm until line 86 from the message:

```
sub _rget {
    my($ftp) = shift;

    my @dirs;

    my @ls = $ftp->dir();

    my @files = $options{ParseSub}->( @ls );

    @files = grep { $_->filename =~ $options{MatchAll} } @files
      if $options{MatchAll};

    @files = grep { $_->filename !~ $options{OmitAll} } @files
      if $options{OmitAll};

    print STDERR join("\n", @ls), "\n"
      if $ftp->debug;

    my $remote_pwd = $ftp->pwd;
    my $local_pwd = Cwd::cwd();

    FILE:
    foreach my $file (@files){
        #used to make sure that if we're deleting the files, we
        #successfully retrieved the file
        my $get_success = 1;
        my $filename = $file->filename();       # <- 86
```

Comment: Now it is obsolete but correct debugging is `Debug => 1` and not `DEBUG => Y 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`yoursub1` is completely wrong. It's suppose to parse the lines returned from the FTP server (provided as arguments to the sub), and return a list of Net::FTP::Recursive::File objects for each remote file (other than `.` and `..`).

If the default implementation (`Net::FTP::Recursive::parse_files`) is sufficient, simply remove `ParseSub => \&yoursub1`. Otherwise, you should probably start by copying `Net::FTP::Recursive::parse_files` and adjusting it for your FTP server's output.

Comment: I removed the function `yoursub1` and the argument in `f1->rget()`. At the end I have only `f1->cwd(); f1->rget();f1->quit();`. This works!. Again, you saved my day.