# Perl Net::FTP::Recursive: Can't download folder but files of subfolders

Tags: perl, ftp, net-ftp

I succeed to download files from a subfolder of the ftp-server. But if I want to download the folders from upper level it does not work.

Here is the folder structure:

- folder         rwx r-x r-x

  - subfolder1   rwx r-x r-x

    - file1   rw- r-- r--
    - file2    rw- r-- r--
  - subfolder2   rxx r-x r-x

    - file3    rw- r-- r--
    - file4    rw- r-- r--

If I use this:

```
$f1->cwd("/folder/subfolder1");
$f1->rget();
$f1->quit;
```

the files file1 and file2 will be downloaded.

If I use this:

```
$f1->cwd("/folder");
$f1->rget();
$f1->quit;
```

nothing will be downloaded and the program finished due to timeout. I expected that it will download subfolder1 and subfolder2 and the content of the subfolders. Is there any explanation for this and how can I solve it in the way that I can download subfolder and files?

A detailled description of the code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53230107/cant-call-method-filename-without-a-package-or-object-reference)

**UPDATE 1:** Debugging

Debugging with

```
my $f1 = Net::FTP::Recursive->new($host1, Debug => 1) or die "Can't open $host1\n";
```

gives the following:

```
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)>>> CWD /folder
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)<<< 250 CWD command successful
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)>>> PWD
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)<<< 257 "/folder" is the current directory
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)>>> PASV
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)<<< 227 Entering Passive Mode (188,40,220,103,255,187).
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)>>> LIST
Net::FTP::Recursive=GLOB(0x312bf50)<<< 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for file list
Timeout at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Net/FTP.pm line 1107.
```

**UPDATE 2:** Timeout at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/Net/FTP.pm line 1107.

`_list_cmd` is the function of the line mentioned in the debug output. I also add the lines where `_list_cmd`is used and wrapped lines to make it more readible conserving line numbers.

```
 671 # Try to delete the contents
 672 # Get a list of all the files in the directory, excluding 
      #     the current and parent directories 
 673 my @filelist = map { /^(?:\S+;)+ (.+)$/ ? ($1) : () } 
          grep { !/^(?:\S+;)*type=[cp]dir;/i } $ftp->_list_cmd("MLSD", $dir);

 925 sub ls  { shift->_list_cmd("NLST", @_); }
 925 sub dir { shift->_list_cmd("LIST", @_); }


1087 sub _list_cmd {
1088   my $ftp = shift;
1089   my $cmd = uc shift;
1090 
1091   delete ${*$ftp}{'net_ftp_port'};
1092   delete ${*$ftp}{'net_ftp_pasv'};
1093 
1094   my $data = $ftp->_data_cmd($cmd, @_);
1095 
1096   return
1097     unless (defined $data);
1098 
1099   require Net::FTP::A;
1100   bless $data, "Net::FTP::A";    # Force ASCII mode
1101 
1102   my $databuf = '';
1103   my $buf     = '';
1104   my $blksize = ${*$ftp}{'net_ftp_blksize'};
1105 
1106   while ($data->read($databuf, $blksize)) {
1107     $buf .= $databuf;
1108   }
1109 
1110   my $list = [split(/\n/, $buf)];
1111 
1112   $data->close();
1114   if (EBCDIC) {
1115     for (@$list) { $_ = $ftp->toebcdic($_) }
1116   }
1117 
1118   wantarray
1119     ? @{$list}
1120     : $list;
1121 }
```

Comment: You might use the `Debug` option for `new` to see what it is actually doing. Maybe this will help to debug the problem.

Comment: @Steffen I used `my $f1 = Net::FTP::Recursive->new($host1, DEBUG => 1) or die "Can't open \$f1 $host1\n";` and it gives no output. Do you have another debug option?

Comment: It is `Debug`, not `DEBUG`. See also the usage example in [the documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::FTP::Recursive).

Comment: @Steffen Thanks, I added debug infos in my question.

Comment: Based on the debug output it looks like the server will not reply in time when doing a listing for `/folder`. Given that it works for `/folder/subfolder1` it looks like a server side problem and not a problem of `Net::FTP::Recursive`.

Answer (score 0):

To download the directories and files a tried the following workaround: using a loop over all subdirectory and appyling `rget`. It does the job I want. Nevertheless, the reason why `rget` does not work on the upper level is still not answered. At least now it is clear that it is not a permission probplem.

```
# ftp-server directory
my $ftpdir = "folder";

# Defie local download folder
my $download = "C:/local";
chdir($download);       

# Change to remote directory
$f1->cwd($ftpdir) or die "Can't cwd to $ftpdir\n", $f1->message;

# grep all folder of top level
my @ftp_directories = $f1->ls;

# remove . and ..
@ftp_subdir = grep ! /^\.+$/, @ftp_subdir;

foreach my $sd (@ftp_subdir) {

    # Make folder on local computer
    my $localdir = catfile($download,$sd);
    mkdir $localdir;

    # Change local working directory
    chdir $localdir;


    # Change to remote sub directory to be downloaded
    $f1->cwd($sd) or die "Can't cwd to $sd\n";
    }

    # download files
    $f1->rget();

    # Change to upper level
    $f1->cwd("..");
}  

$f1->quit;
```